# struggling to reset slider input in javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

I am loading an image and changing its properties using a slider bar.

This is my slider

```
<label for="red">Red</label>
<input type="range" min="-255" max="255" value="0" id="red">
```

When the image is changed I am trying to set the slider back to its original value of zero

```js
fileinput.onchange = function (e) {
    // document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    // getElementById('red').MaterialSlider.change(0);
    red.MaterialSlider.change(0);
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.item(0)) {
       srcImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    }
}
```

I do have this in my js file

```js
 const red = document.getElementById('red')
```

I tried doing it three ways including putting the slider inside a form and resetting the form. None of them have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Simply

red.value = 0;